# mapView.showsUserLocation = true affects the correctness of gps in my swift app. Why?

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, cllocationmanager, cllocation

In my app I want to know user's real location. I want to show it in couple places as a plain text (as a string of longitude/latitude) and also show it on the map. I have several ui view controllers and one of them contains - now, for testing - a print to the console with current longitude and latitude, it also contains a map view.

I'm fetching the current gps position from my app delegate and put it on the screen.

In my AppDelegate.swift class I have:

```
var locationManager: CLLocationManager! = nil
var location: CLLocation! = nil
var longitude : Double = 0
var latitude : Double = 0
var location_fixed = false

func application(application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        initLocationManager()
}

func initLocationManager() {
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .AuthorizedAlways {
        locationManager!.startUpdatingLocation()
    } else {
        locationManager!.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    print("Failed to initialize GPS: ", error.description)
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    location = locations.first!
    print("Managed to get a fix on location")
    let coord = location.coordinate
    longitude = coord.longitude
    latitude = coord.latitude
    location_fixed = true;
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

    switch status {
    case .NotDetermined:
        print("NotDetermined")
    case .Restricted:
        print("Restricted")
    case .Denied:
        print("Denied")
    case .AuthorizedAlways:
        print("AuthorizedAlways")
        locationManager!.startUpdatingLocation()
    case .AuthorizedWhenInUse:
        print("AuthorizedWhenInUse")
        locationManager!.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

func stopGPS() -> Void
{
    print("STOP GPS")
     location_fixed = false;
     locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

}

func startGPS() -> Void
{
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func isLocationFixed() -> Bool
{
    return self.location_fixed
}

func getLongitude() -> Double
{
    return self.longitude
}

func getLatitude() -> Double
{
    return self.latitude
}

func getLocation() -> CLLocation
{
    return self.location
}
```

Now in my `UIViewController` in `viewWillAppear` method I added asynchronous call to the app delegate methods for checking current gps position:

```
    let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.startGPS()

        while (!appDelegate.isLocationFixed())
        {
            sleep(1)

        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.fetchRequests(self.radius, lat: appDelegate.getLatitude(), lon: appDelegate.getLongitude())
            print("gps here: \(appDelegate.getLatitude()), \(appDelegate.getLongitude())")            }
    }
```

and now when I enter this panel and waits for fetching the gps - I see the correct data. So far so good. Now, when I change the gps position in a simulator, then go to some other panel and come back to this one - I see the new data, which is fine.

And now comes the real weird problem. In the same panel I have a map view.

It's embedded in a `UIViewController` that I put in a container, so I cannot access it from my async call. It has a `viewDidLoad()` method and when I put there:

```
mapView.showsUserLocation = true
```

and run the app, I see the blue dot exactly when the simulator's gps points out, but now my data in the previous async call is not updating correctly.

When I comment out that one particular line of code, I'm getting the correct data shown as `gps here:`. When I leave it as a part of the code, then this line `gps here:` shows the same data all the time, even though I'm changing the gps position in a simulator, leaving and entering the panel several times. What's up with that?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are seeing the issue, but I can say that polling is horrible. Also on a real device you will see location accuracy improve over time. Rather than have the `locationFixed` boolean I would suggest that your app delegate exposes an optional `location`, so if it isn't nil you have a location. Have your `didUpdateLocation` function post an NSNotification when there is a new location and have your view controllers subscribe to that. This will avoid polling. Don't call `stopUodatingLocation` after the first fix as that first fix is likely to be +/- 1000m or more on a real device

Comment: Hm, could you explain me in couple words what exactly do you mean by polling?

Comment: The code where you check the Boolean in a while loop with a sleep is polling, ie simply waiting in a loop for some condition. This is inefficient. In modern UI driven applications (and particularly on mobile devices where battery needs to be conserved) you should use event-driven programming. In this case the location manager posts an event via the delegate when it has a location. You can send this event to interested parties using NSNotifications